# How to automatically install entire Google Web Fonts collection?

Tags: installation, fonts, scripts, google

I'm basically looking for an unattended way to deploy/install the [Google Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts) collection into several Ubuntu boxes. I've searched for PPAs, packages or user scripts but without much luck.

Any advice will be much appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 11):

The existing answer in this post is out dated and does not work (specifically, the remote hg repository no longer exists).

New instructions are available here: https://github.com/google/fonts

In summary:

```
wget https://github.com/google/fonts/archive/master.zip
unzip master.zip
```

Then, as previously:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/share/fonts/truetype/google-fonts/
find ./fonts-master/ -name "*.ttf" -exec sudo install -m644 {} /usr/share/fonts/truetype/google-fonts/ \; || return 1
fc-cache -f > /dev/null
```

Comment: I get this error: find ./fonts-master/ -name "*.ttf" -exec sudo install -m644 {} /usr/share/fonts/truetype/google-fonts/ \; || return 1
fc-cache -f > /dev/null
find: ‘./fonts-master/’: No such file or directory
bash: return: can only `return' from a function or sourced script

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried this:
http://www.webupd8.org/2011/01/automatically-install-all-google-web.html

Comment: I did and not only it failed but also installed the Mercurial client and whatnot - I'm currently looking for a cleaner approach.

Comment: Even the official instructions point out to using Mercurial: http://code.google.com/p/googlefontdirectory/ . The script works just fine here... maybe you're behind a proxy or something that blocks Mercurial?

Comment: I believe the tutorial is not being very informative about the location of `googlefontdirectory` and that's why applications such as Gimp or Inkscape are currently unable to load them. Do you mind providing us with some instructions regarding how to achieve this?

Comment: The script in that posts installs the fonts system-wide (under /usr/share/fonts/truetype/google-fonts ) and then updates the font cache using "fc-cache -f" so they will be picked up by Gimp, etc.

Comment: simply awesome !