# Download Google web fonts, how to install it?

Tags: installation, fonts

I used Terminal to download Google web fonts using commands listed below

```
apt-get install -y mercurial;    
hg clone https://googlefontdirectory.googlecode.com/hg/googlefontdirectory;
```

I now have a directory in my home folder called " Google Font Directory ". It has sub folder named " ofl " which all font in separate folder. It seems there are 680 items. So dragging and dropping them to .fonts folder is almost impossible. Is there any method to install them automatically ? I have " Type Catcher " (just for your info). Please help me with this. Thanks.

PS : I use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Comment: Woops you're right, didn's see that one :)

Comment: Will I have to download from scratch again ? :(

Comment: I am trying font manager. It has scanned the folder and got all font files. Just need to install them. As they are very heavy, waiting for my other works to finish. Will try to update here with results. :)

Answer (score 3):

A better way is to use the script described here:

http://www.webupd8.org/2011/01/automatically-install-all-google-web.html

Just run these three commands:

```
cd && wget http://webupd8.googlecode.com/files/install-google-fonts
chmod +x install-google-fonts
./install-google-fonts
```

Comment: Good answer, though I think this one is going to be closed as a dupe of http://askubuntu.com/questions/53965/how-to-automatically-install-entire-google-web-fonts-collection?rq=1

Comment: @ RPi, you don't get me, don't you ? I have the fonts. I just want to install them. It took a whole day with my slow internet to download it. But now I can't even use them. That is why I tried a help request here. It is no dupe but entirely different cases.

Comment: @darent. Thanks for the reply. Would I have to download all fonts again. I am asking this because I use a slow internet connection and it will take a lot of time to download them again. Please help me understand better. Thanks again.